# Implementing module federation, app-router, and webpack with Next.js 13 - how to fix 'client-only' error?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, webpack-module-federation, app-router

I am currently working on implementing `module federation` in `Next.js 13.4.4`, utilizing the `app-router` feature and the `@module-federation/nextjs-mf` package. In order to achieve a micro front-end architecture, I have created a host app that imports remote modules and renders them on specific pages. However, when I add my webpack configuration, I encounter the following error:

```
./node_modules\next\dist\compiled\client-only\error.js
'client-only' cannot be imported from a Server Component module. It should only be used from a Client Component.

Import trace for the requested module:
./node_modules\next\dist\compiled\client-only\error.js
./node_modules\styled-jsx\dist\index\index.js
./node_modules\styled-jsx\style.js
./node_modules@module-federation\nextjs-mf\src\include-defaults.js
./src\app\page.js
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my configuration on `next.config.js` :

```
const { NextFederationPlugin } = require('@module-federation/nextjs-mf');

const remotes = (isServer) => {
  const location = isServer ? 'ssr' : 'chunks';
  return {
    remoteApp: `remoteApp@http://localhost:3001/_next/static/${location}/remoteEntry.js`
  };
}

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  experimental: {
    esmExternals: false,
  },
  webpack(config, { isServer }) {
      config.plugins.push(
        new NextFederationPlugin({
          name: 'host',
          filename: 'static/chunks/remoteEntry.js',
          remotes: remotes(isServer),
          exposes: {},
          shared: {},
          extraOptions:{
            automaticAsyncBoundary: true
          }
        })
      );
    

    return config;
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Also, I import the remote into a page:

```
// src/pages/hostPage.js

"use client"
const Remote = dynamic(
    () => import('remoteApp/NewPage').then((mod) => mod.NewPage),
    {
        ssr: false,
    }
);
export function Home() {
    return (
        <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
            <h1 className='text-white'>This is host</h1>
            <Remote />
        </main>
    )
}
export default Home;
```

Related dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "13.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
    "@module-federation/utilities": "1.7.3",
    "@module-federation/nextjs-mf": "6.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.76.2"
  }
```

Comment: You are trying to import a component or a part of code on the server that needs to run on the client side. Please read the documentation for the difference between [client and server side code](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials).

Comment: @FabioNettis thanks for the comment, I tried using the "use client" directive. also, I moved the page out of the app directory into the pages. I'm not sure what I missed here

Comment: The stack trace points to `/src/app/page.js`, have you tried to add the `"use client"` directive there? Since you seem to only have posted `/src/pages/hostPage.js`. From what I have seen module federation has an [example repository](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/tree/master/nextjs-v13) for Next.js 13. Maybe you should check that out too.

Comment: @FabioNettis Yes I did, I found out the implementation does not affect the Error, but as soon as I remove the `NextFederationPlugin`  part located on `next.config.js`, the error will disappear

Comment: Looks like the `NextFederationPlugin ` seems to be the root of your problem then, as stated above check out the [example repository](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/tree/master/nextjs-v13). Maybe you'll find helpful information there.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue, and there's an open issue on github here :
https://github.com/module-federation/universe/issues/953

I created a PR which addresses the problem, we'll see what Zack Jackson says... in the meantime you can follow the pattern used in the [example repo](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/blob/master/nextjs-v13/checkout/next.config.js#L7) which does not apply the federation plugin on server side builds.